# How to style signature links in Outlook for Gmail?

Tags: html, css, outlook, gmail, apple-mail

I'm creating an email signature in Microsoft Outlook. I'm aware that the formatting will never be 100% consistent across all email readers, but I'd settle for the most used platforms in our company displaying them correctly: Outlook, Gmail and Apple Mail.

The problem is links. Using a custom colour on links works without a hitch when the email is received in Outlook. Gmail and Apple Mail, however, colour the text your custom colour, but the underline reverts to the default browser blue or purple.

I would settle for either of these two outcomes:

1. Removing the underline from links.
2. Having the same underline colour as the text.

I have been up and down the internet and cannot find a solution that works. Many say they have a fix, but articles and comments are dated from 2012 or 2014. Obviously, Gmail and Apple Mail have evolved since then.

Last year Gmail started supporting responsive design in emails, allowing `<style>` tags to be added to the `<head>` section. Surely it should be possible to crack this now?

I've tried every little trick I could find, wrapping my link in a `<span>`, wrapping the `<span>` in the link. I've tried similar tricks with and without the `<font>` tag. Basically I have tried every nested and redundant combination of these. Here's a sample of my last effort:

```
<body link="#59b5ba" alink="#59b5ba" vlink="#59b5ba" text="#59b5ba">

<a href="#" style="color:#59b5ba;text-decoration:none;text-decoration-color:#59b5ba;-webkit-text-decoration-color:#59b5ba;">
    <span style="color:#59b5ba;text-decoration:none;text-decoration-color:#59b5ba;-webkit-text-decoration-color:#59b5ba;">
        <font color="#59b5ba">
            Link
        </font>
    </span>
</a>

</body>
```

It should also be noted that I've tried `text-decoration:underline` as well with the same result.

Has anyone successfully managed to remove the underline or make the line colour match the text?

Comment: Hi, did you ever manage to resolve this issue?